# Javascript: Does Inner HTML update during the forloop or after the entire loop is run?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

I just wanted to improve my e-commerce website performance in terms of appending new items to it. We have a lot of items to display so I'm wondering if this would work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for (item of items) {
item_display_div.innerHTML += item; // Would the item_display_div only start updating here?
}
// Or here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating onto the `innerHTML` of an element will force the browser to completely re-parse the HTML markup inside and create new elements. If you do that many times in a loop, it could be expensive. Example:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<img src onerror="console.log(`img tag 1 errorred`)">';

document.body.innerHTML += '<img src onerror="console.log(`img tag 2 errorred`)">';
```

See how the first `<img>` tag gets parsed *twice* - first after the first `.innerHTML +=`, and again after the second `.innerHTML +=`.

Better to use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) - append the elements to the fragment, then append the fragment at the very end.

Also, whenever you do have to insert plain HTML markup, at least consider using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `.innerHTML +=` - `insertAdjacentHTML` does *not* force the container to re-parse any of its elements.

Comment: Ahh icic. Thank you!!